# Sort posts by ACF date and add title for each month

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create an archive page for my blog posts that is sorted by the date that is added through an ACF datepicker-field.

This is what I have so far:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'         =>  'post',
'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
'orderby'           =>  'meta_value',
'order'             =>  'DESC',
'meta_key'          =>  'datum_artikel',
'meta_value'        =>  date('Ymd',strtotime("today")),
'meta_compare'      =>  '<='
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo "<div class='posts'>";

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            $f = get_fields();
            $link = ($f['bericht_doorverwijzen'] ?? '' ? $f['bericht_doorverwijzen'] : get_the_permalink());
            $img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

            $date = $f['datum_artikel'];

            echo "<div class='post w-1/3'>";
                echo "<div class='postWrapper'>";

                    if(!empty($img_id)) {
                        $img = Images::get_image_resized($img_id, 397, 230, true);
                        echo "<a href='".$link."' title='Ga naar ".get_the_title()."'>";
                            echo '<picture class="img">';
                                echo '<img src="'.$img[0].'" alt="'.get_post_meta($img_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true).'"/>';
                            echo '</picture>';
                        echo "</a>";
                    }

                    echo "<div class='content'>";
                        echo "<h2><a href='".$link."' title='Ga naar ".get_the_title()."'>".get_the_title()."</a></h2>";
                        if(!empty($date)) {
                            echo "<p class='date'>". $date ."</p>";
                        }
                        echo the_excerpt_max_charlength($charlength = 130);
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    echo "</div>";
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I found some examples online but none of them seem to work with my code. How can I add the name of the month between the posts when the month changes and can I create an extra navigation with all the months and an anchor so it jumps to the right posts?

Comment: Looking at the `orderBy` field above I see you are using `meta_value` in descending order. What about changing `meta_value` to `datum_artikel`?

Comment: The order of the posts is how I need it, the only thing that I want is to display a title between the different posts when the month changes between two posts.

Comment: Then you want to implement a classic _control break_. You simply compare the value of the criterion (month, resp. the combination of year and month) of the current record, with that of the previous one - if they differ, then you output the month first, and then proceed with outputting the data of the current record.

Comment: What format is `$date` in? Can you paste an example?

Comment: $date has this format: j F Y

Answer (score 1):

I found another example online that seems to do what what I need:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type'     => 'post',
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'meta_key'      => 'datum_artikel',
'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
'order'         => 'DESC',
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $current_header = "";

    echo "<div class='posts'>";

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $f = get_fields();
            $date = $f['datum_artikel'];
            $temp_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'datum_artikel', true);
            $pretty_month = date_i18n("F Y", strtotime($temp_date));

            if ($pretty_month != $current_header) {
                $current_header = $pretty_month;
                echo "<h2>". $pretty_month ."</h2>";
            }


            $link = ($f['bericht_doorverwijzen'] ?? '' ? $f['bericht_doorverwijzen'] : get_the_permalink());
            $img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

            echo "<div class='post w-1/3'>";
                echo "<div class='postWrapper'>";

                    if(!empty($img_id)) {
                        $img = Images::get_image_resized($img_id, 397, 230, true);
                        echo "<a href='".$link."' title='Ga naar ".get_the_title()."'>";
                            echo '<picture class="img">';
                                echo '<img src="'.$img[0].'" alt="'.get_post_meta($img_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true).'"/>';
                            echo '</picture>';
                        echo "</a>";
                    }

                    echo "<div class='content'>";
                        echo "<h2><a href='".$link."' title='Ga naar ".get_the_title()."'>".get_the_title()."</a></h2>";
                        if(!empty($date)) {
                            echo "<p class='date'>". $date ."</p>";
                        }
                        echo the_excerpt_max_charlength($charlength = 130);
                        echo "<a href='".$link."' title='Ga naar ".get_the_title()."' class='link'>Lees meer</a>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date("Y/m/j");
$args = (array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
    'meta_key' => 'datum_artikel',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'datum_artikel',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    )
));
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```